# Batch "Not a duplicate"

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Within Civi's UI, there is an option to mark "not a duplicate" when you go through the "Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts" process. I can mark not a duplicate one by one, but I would like to check off a bunch of them and do a batch "not a duplicate". Is this possible in the UI?

I tried the check boxes to the left of the contacts to make a selection and then clicking "not a duplicate", but that didn't work.